# App's Google Play URL not showing in Google Search

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-search, android-app-links

I have an App published in Google Play but the market's link is not ranked in Google Search. The Play Store link is

*https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ekasa.com.retabet.full*

Whenever I try to search in Google the Play Store link is not showing. The App was published last year. I have tried linking the App with my website in the Google Play Console and uploading assetslinks.json file as stated in the resources for App Linking in Android.

Any clue?

BR

Comment: Are u sure, that your app is published, cause the link says: page not found

Comment: Yes, the App is only published in the Spanish store